# 500 Backend Error on streaming API

Tags: google-bigquery

so I have a scheduler running which pushes 500 rows to bigquery at every 2 seconds using "insertAll" streaming API. It inserts successfully for initial few batches but after sometime it receives following exception
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
`{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}`

Any idea what could be the reason?

Thanks,
Ved

Comment: Do you have a job id?

Comment: Alas, `insertAll` doesn't create a job id, so insertAll issues can be much more difficult to track down. Can you send your project id and an approximate time that the last error happened? Also, error 500s are bigquery bugs, so you can also report them here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the swift response. It happened just now with the above mentioned scenario. It gave this error after pushing approx 4000 rows at the rate of 500 rows at every 2 seconds. My Project-Id is "deft-virtue-628". And this happened just now at 10:30 IST (12:00 AM EST). Will report at above mentioned link as well, but if possible please let us know if we can get rid of it as in our scenario it requires to push the data at above rate by 24x7 and this can be show stopper for us. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have the same problem. As I assume it'll take a while before this bug being solved, I'm wondering what's the suggested workaround we can do for now? Right now I put the data back into my request queue and resent them until I got a success. Will this cause data duplication?

Comment: In the case of resending in the face of backendErrors, the tabledata.insertAll call does allow you to supply unique insertIds to enable deduplication:  see the [troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#troubleshooting) section of the streaming documentation.

Comment: yes, but it says it's based on best try , and it remembers insertId for at least one minute. So I guess it won't ensure no duplicates at all

Comment: Correct.  Its performing the deduplication against rows that have been recently buffered, not the entirety of data in the target table.